# Maximum with a custom ordering

Tags: julia

I have a array like the following:

```
julia> list = [(x, rand(0:9), rand(0:9)) for x in 1:5]
5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (1, 7, 2)
 (2, 1, 3)
 (3, 4, 7)
 (4, 4, 8)
 (5, 8, 3)
```

I'd like to find the element in that list whose *third value* is greatest.  If I just do `maximum(list)`, it uses the default (lexicographic) ordering, which is not what I want:

```
julia> maximum(list)
(5, 8, 3)
```

I can use a custom `by` transformation/predicate if I sort the entire list:

```
julia> sort(list, by=x->x[3], rev=true)
5-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}:
 (4, 4, 8)
 (3, 4, 7)
 (2, 1, 3)
 (5, 8, 3)
 (1, 7, 2)
```

But that does a lot of extra work — all I need is that first value — but it appears `maximum` does not support the `by` keyword argument:

```
julia> maximum(list, by=x->x[3])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching maximum(::Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},1}; by=var"#21#22"())
```

And if I use the "transforming" first argument function, I only get the third value back:

```
julia> maximum(x->x[3], list)
8
```

I want the entire element — `(4, 4, 8)` in this case.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

While `maximum` does not support `by` keyword, it does support a "transformer" function.  In this particular case, we can find the maximum of the *reversed* elements, and then reverse it back:

```
julia> reverse(maximum(reverse, list))
(4, 4, 8)
```

More generally, you can use the sorting infrastructure (with all its fancy `by` transformers and custom `lt` comparisons) without actually sorting the entire list with `partialsort`:

```
julia> partialsort(list, 1, by=x->x[3], rev=true)
(4, 4, 8)
```

This isn't quite as efficient but it's far more capable — and it saves quite a bit over sorting the entire thing.  With a larger vector:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> list = [(x, rand(0:9), rand(0:9)) for x in 1:10_000];

julia> @btime reverse(maximum(reverse, $list));
  7.833 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime partialsort($list, 1, by=x->x[3], rev=true);
  37.772 μs (3 allocations: 234.48 KiB)

julia> @btime sort($list, by=x->x[3], rev=true);
  339.570 μs (5 allocations: 351.81 KiB)
```

Comment: It's perhaps also worth noting that adding support for the `by` keyword to `maximum` is an open feature request — hopefully it'll be supported someday! https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28210

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use `sortperm` to get the permutation indices of the reduced array (only containing the keys by which you want to sort), and then use those indices to sort the full array:

```
a = [(x, rand(0:9), rand(0:9)) for x in 1:5]
perm = sortperm(a, by=x->x[3], rev=true)
b = a[perm]
```

Or in case you're only interested in the maximum, use

```
b_max = a[perm[1]]
```

Or

```
i_max = findmax(map(x->x[3], a)[2]
b_max = a[i_max]
```

Comment: Nice, thanks!  These are good alternatives. They will be a bit slower if you only need the maximum — `sortperm` sorts the entire array, but you could use `partialsortperm` to limit the work as a drop-in replacement.  Ideally `findmax`/`argmax` would also support a transformer function like `maximum` does, but doing that operation ahead of time requires a temporary array. It's an open feature request: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/27613